# How do I change a standard library project to be a silverlight library project?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, compilation

I've downloaded the Ninject SVN visual studio project and I want to compile it against Silverlight libraries to make a Silverlight compatible DLL.

Is there a setting to change somewhere to make it a Silverlight library project, or do I need to swap in and out references here and there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting, you will need to swap in the appropriate SL libraries, its not just "here and there" its actually "everywhere".  You then need to hope that the project doesn't use anything that isn't present in the SL libraries.